# How to "remove" an element from an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, replace, char

*Read a lot of different answers but couldn´t find a way to fix this, so here I am with yet a "how-to" question.*

So I´m trying to "remove" an element from an array I´ve created. As I´ve understood it, there is no way to simply remove an element, rather you would need to move proceeding elements to the left of the array, thus overwriting the element you dont want with already existing elements.

Tried to do exactly that in my removeToDoItem-function, but the error I am getting is: **assigment to expression with array type.** Been following this tutorial https://codeforwin.org/2015/07/c-program-to-delete-element-from-array.html, but it seems like I am missing something.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Listsize 10
#define Stringsize 30
#include <string.h>

 void printToDolist(char toDolist[][Stringsize], int placering)
{
    for(int i= 0; i<placering; i++)
        printf("%d - %s\n", i+1, toDolist[i]);
}

int addToDoItem(char toDolist[][Stringsize], int placering)
{
    int i;
    for( i=1; i<=3; i++)
    {
    printf(" Add a note: ");
    fgets(toDolist[i], 30 , stdin);
    }

    return placering+i;
}

int removeToDoItem(char toDolist[][Stringsize], int placering)
{

    int position,i;


    printf(" Which element would you like to remove?: ");
    scanf("%d", &position);

    for(i=position-1; i< placering-1; i++)
    {
        toDolist[i] = toDolist[i+1];

    }
        return placering--;
}
```

int main()

```
{
char toDolist[Listsize][Stringsize] = {[0]= "Buy candy \n"};

int placering = 0;
placering = addToDoItem(toDolist, placering);
printToDolist(toDolist, placering);
removeToDoItem(toDolist, placering);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line does your error message refer to?

Comment: @ScottHunter toDolist[i] = toDolist[i+1], in the remove-function

Comment: @pmg Thanks man, that worked. Totally forgot that strcpy could be used in this instance xD. Cheers m8!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     for(i=position-1; i< placering-1; i++)
>     {
>         toDolist[i] = toDolist[i+1]; // wrong: cannot assign to an array
>                                      // toDolist[i] is an array of 30 characters
>     }
> ```

You want

```
     for (i = position - 1; i < placering - 1; i++) {
         strcpy(toDolist[i], toDolist[i + 1]);
     }
```

Comment: Yup, this worked. Gotta wait 8 minutes before I can accept an answer (for some reason), but this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead of `toDolist[i] = toDolist[i+1]`.

Also you do not actually delete the item properly. If you would have the string array: "one", "two", "three". And lets say you would delete the first item "one" the resulting array would be "two", three", "three". Which might not cause issue for your particular program, but it might better to set the last element of the array to empty string "" also to avoid strange results.

Also you dont use the return value of your`removeToDoItem` function to overwrite the old `placering` value with new one. And also if you `return placering--`, what will happen that it will return `placering` without decreasing it since it post increment. Do rather this `return placering - 1`.

Comment: Oh yea, sitting with the code atm and I just realised this. How do I use the return value?

Comment: just as you did with `placering = addToDoItem(toDolist, placering);`

Comment: *Face palm* Thanks dude.

Comment: Wrote something, but your edited version fixed it. Yet again, thanks dude. Do you have any tips on how to become proficient in C? Really need to learn when to use post-increment and not.

Comment: Just write code and you run into problems and learn from them. I do not consider myself either proficient. Just as you code you will time to time run into problems and eventually find out what caused them and you learn from it. You might now know that if you use a variable with post increment than first its original value will be used then the increment happens. The next day you might learn something else and eventually build up your knowledge.

Try to solve problems by yourself first, but dont be afraid to ask. If you want to speed up the process than read some books like C primer.